# JSF select one menu set wrong

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, hashmap, selectonemenu

i'm using select one menu to select from `map<String,Integer>` but it just select `0` :

```
 <p:fieldset id="locations" legend="locations" toggleable="false">
        <p:selectOneMenu id="locations" value="#{bean.selectedLocation}" filter="true" filterMatchMode="contains">
            <f:selectItems value="#{bean.availableLocations}"/>
        </p:selectOneMenu>
    </p:fieldset>
```

and my bean is:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Bean  {
private Map<String, Integer> availableLocations = new HashMap<>();
private int                  selectedLocation   = 1;


public int getSelectedLocation() {
    return selectedLocation;
}
public void setSelectedLocation(int selectedLocation) {
    this.selectedLocation=selectedLocation;
}

@Override
protected void init() {
        availableLocations.clear();
        availableLocations.putAll(Locations.getLocations());
}
```

}

when i select any items, it just set `0` as `selectedLocation`

when i put my fieldset into the form it never set anything

thanks in advance,

Comment: To exclude one and other, what if you set `converter="javax.faces.Integer"` on menu component?

Comment: thank you @BalusC, no it doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

i found the problem

by adding an `ajax`, problem will resolve

```
<p:ajax event="change" update="@this" />
```

Comment: Oh? So your main form submit button isn't processing the menu value at all? Are you using `process="@this"` in the submit button or so? If so, then your answer is merely a workaround and not a real solution.

Comment: no, this form just has a select one menu to select a variable on bean, also this form contain another field set which not render when this field set rendered

Comment: You've a bigger problem. Regardless, in future questions please remember to post a real MCVE. Nothing of this all was visible in the question in its current form. You could impossibly have received the answer you really needed from someone who don't have insight in the actual code. See also http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info.